# How do you put api routes in the new app folder of Next.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have a test API under: `pages\api\accounts\login.js`. And I am learning the new `app` folder, which is still an experimental feature in Next.js (as of today).

Is it possible to move my login script into the `app` folder? I tried moving/renaming to `app\api\accounts\login\pages.js`, but when I do this:

```
async function handler(req, res) {
  console.log(res);
}
export default handler;
```

I use the URL: `http://localhost:3000/api/accounts/login`. I get:

> Server Error
>
> Error: Cannot find module for page: /api/accounts/login

I also tried moving it to: `app/api/accounts/login/page.js`. But I get the same error.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Since version `13.2`, we have API [Route Handlers](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/routing/route-handlers) in the [`app`](https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/project-structure) folder. They work like pages, but the file for the segment should be called `route.js` instead of `page.js`.

For example, say you have the below file structure and code:

[image]

```js
// app/api/route.js 

import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

// To handle a GET request to /api
export async function GET(request) {
  // Do whatever you want
  return NextResponse.json({ message: "Hello World" }, { status: 200 });
}

// To handle a POST request to /api
export async function POST(request) {
  // Do whatever you want
  return NextResponse.json({ message: "Hello World" }, { status: 200 });
}

// Same logic to add a `PATCH`, `DELETE`...
```

You can access `/api` as any API route, for example, with `fetch("/api")`. While going to `/` renders `page.js`.

Comment: Here you mentioned the post badge and it seems the GET function is inside the route.js so it is GET or POST request?

Also if I want to create post API, How can I do this?

Comment: Hi Kishan! I updated the code snippet, check it out.

Answer (score 11):

This has changed as of last week.

The new app folder requires a route.ts under the pathing.

For instance if you want app/api/accounts/login, your file pathing should be

app/api/accounts/login/route.ts

route.ts will be inside of your login folder and contains all of the logic for your api endpoint. For example

[image: APP Api Example]

Each folder is an endpoint, and requires a route.ts. To the best of my knowledge this is how it works, but I am still learning the new app directory.

Answer (score 4):

Api routes in `app` directory is quite simple, actually, but it's still beta. Using your example, you would have to create a file like this: `app\api\accounts\login\routes.ts` and inside this file export one function for each HTTP method that the route needs to respond to:

Ex: `export async function POST (request: Request) {}`

You can check more info [here](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/routing/route-handlers) and [here](https://nextjs.org/blog/next-13-2#custom-route-handlers) and maybe [here](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/file-conventions/route)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the App Router, you can use [Server Components](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/fetching) or [Route Handlers](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/router-handlers) instead of API Routes.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this in two ways the number one is to use the flow that the other answers had mentioned
make something like this

```
app\api\routes.ts
```

the other way i wanna mention is the old way but it has many features of the response and request object of node.js and its like your code

```js
async function handler(req, res) {
  console.log(res);
}
export default handler;
```

and the directory you should define is

```
rootdirectory/pages/api/example.ts
```

note that pages dir should be parallel with your app directory, by this way you can leverage the node.js legacy methods of req and res which are so useful.