# NextJS 13 Beta App Directory API with Prisma

Tags: next.js, prisma, next.js13

as we now NextJS released their update to have access to api's within the APP directory and I've had trouble getting prisma to work with it. I can get prisma to work fully functional with pages/api, but not with app/api. Wondering if there was anyone that has managed to get this to work yet. If so, any tips would be greatly appreciated.

I tried to replicate the same structure from pages/api -> app/api (with the new route handlers) with NextJS new APP directory API.

Sample of what I am trying to do.

```
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";
const prisma = new PrismaClient();

export default async function handle(req:any, res:any) {
    const { firstname, lastname, dateofbirth, email, password } = req.body;

    const addUser: any = await prisma.owners.create({
        data: {
            firstname: firstname,
            lastname: lastname,
            dateofbirth: dateofbirth,
            email: email,
            password: password,
        },
    });
    res.json(addUser)

}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you put api routes in the new app folder of Next.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75418329/how-do-you-put-api-routes-in-the-new-app-folder-of-next-js)

Comment: No, not at all. I know how the APP api directory works, I was just confused on getting prisma to work with the new api route handlers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are creating a user (owner) in your example, I assume that your old endpoint was in the following file: `/pages/api/owners.ts`

The new endpoint could be created with the following structure: `/app/api/owners/route.ts` and could look like this with the new [Route Handlers](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/routing/route-handlers):

```js
// create user
export async function POST(req: Request) {

  // assuming your body has json data
  const { firstname, lastname, dateofbirth, email, password } = await req.json();

  const addUser: any = await prisma.owners.create({
    data: {
        firstname: firstname,
        lastname: lastname,
        dateofbirth: dateofbirth,
        email: email,
        password: password,
    },
  });

  return Response.json(addUser);
}
```