# nextjs server not starting and api call not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, next.js, backend

Below is my code for a component in my Next.js app:

```
const [apiResponse, setApiResponse] = useState('');
const callApi = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch('/api/your-endpoint');
    const data = await response.json();
    console.log(data); // Add this line
    setApiResponse(data.text);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error calling API:', error);
  }
};

return (
  <>
    <button onClick={callApi}>Call API</button>
    <div>{apiResponse}</div>
  </>
);
```

Below is my code for the server:

```
const { NextServer } = require('next/server');

const server = new NextServer({});

// API Route
server.get('/api/your-endpoint', (req, res) => {
  res.json({ text: 'This is another Server (Backend) Test' });
});

// Start the server
server.listen(3005, (err) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('> Ready on http://localhost:3005');
});
```

Whenever I click on call api nothing happens. I have shared my directory structure below.

Please tell me what i am doing wrong.

[image]

Comment: Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75418329/how-do-you-put-api-routes-in-the-new-app-folder-of-next-js?