# Fetch API route in /app folder in Next JS 13

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to create an API and fetch data in Next JS 13. I've read this question: [How do you put api routes in the new app folder of Next.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75418329/how-do-you-put-api-routes-in-the-new-app-folder-of-next-js)

and came up with these:

`/src/app/hooks/useLocation.ts`:

```
export const getUserLocation = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if ("geolocation" in navigator) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(({coords}) => {
        const {latitude, longitude} = coords;
        resolve({latitude, longitude});
      }, (error) => {
        reject(error);
      });
    } else {
      reject("Geolocation not available");
    }
  });
};
```

`/src/app/location/route.ts`:

```
import {getUserLocation} from "@/app/hooks/useLocation";
import {NextResponse} from "next/server";

export async function GET() {
  const userLocation = getUserLocation();
  return NextResponse.json(userLocation);
}
```

And `/src/app/layout.tsx`:

```
'use server';
import './globals.scss'

interface LayoutProps {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}
export default async function RootLayout({ children }: LayoutProps) {
  try {
    const response = await fetch('/api/location', {
      method: 'GET',
      cache: 'no-store',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    });

    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error('Response error');
    };

    const responseData = await response.json();
    console.log(responseData);
    return responseData;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
  };

  return (
    <html lang="en">
    <body>
    <main className="flex min-h-screen flex-col items-center justify-between p-24 main">
      {children}
    </main>
    </body>
    </html>
  )
};
```

However when running, I got error:

```
Error fetching data: TypeError: Failed to parse URL from /api/location
    at new Request (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:7004:19)
    at T (C:\projects\xiaohan-du\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page-experimental.runtime.dev.js:34:233400)
    ... 13 lines matching cause stack trace ...
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  [cause]: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_URL]: Invalid URL
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few reasons why it won't work properly,

1. Your API route `/src/app/location/route.ts` isn't proper, keep your API in `src/app/api/folderNameAsAPIName/route.js`. **Make api folder & then make a folder inside it with API Name & inside it a route.js/ts file.** Read Here Route Handlers https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/route-handlers. This is probably the reason why it gives error `Error fetching data: TypeError: Failed to parse URL from /api/location` `TypeError [ERR_INVALID_URL]: Invalid URL` as there is no api folder in `src/app`.
2. [Geolocation API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation_API) & [Navigator API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator) are client side(it runs in browser) you have called it in `/api` folder which is server-side, hence it wont run. (it will show Error `ReferenceError: navigator is not defined`). Read More [Navigator: geolocation property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/geolocation)
3. `'use client'` to do client side operations like events you should add 'use client' at top of that component & import it in page. That component will be rendered client side. Read More https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/client-components
4. *Please read this part*, Benefits of Client Rendering https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/client-components#benefits-of-client-rendering

**Here's a small code that I made (it's in .js you may re-write it in .ts):**

**Folder Structure :**

```
projectName
├── .gitignore
├── jsconfig.json
├── next.config.js
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
├── postcss.config.js
├── public
│   ├── next.svg
│   └── vercel.svg
├── README.md
├── src
│   └── app
│       ├── api
│       │   └── location
│       │       └── route.js
│       ├── comp
│       │   └── Loc.js
│       ├── favicon.ico
│       ├── globals.css
│       ├── hooks
│       │   └── useLocation.js
│       ├── layout.js
│       └── page.js
└── tailwind.config.js
```

comp is component folder.

1. `useLocation` hook remains as it is in its current folder.
2. Then under `src/app/api/` I made a folder `location` & inside it a file `route.js`.

This Location  API will return `Location API says Hello !!` & when you uncomment those 2 lines above, you will see error :

**Code inside `src/app/api/location/route.js`**

```
import { getUserLocation } from "@/app/hooks/useLocation";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export async function GET() {

    console.log("Location API was HIT !");

    // let location = await getUserLocation()
    // console.log(location);

    // UN COMMENT THE ABOVE TO SEE THE ERROR

    return NextResponse.json({ data: "Location API says Hello !!" });
}
```

Then i made a component inside which i will get Location using that hook & also i made a call to our location api :

**Loc Component code** :

**Note** : the api url is `/api/location` is correct as per NextJS convention.

```
'use client'
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { getUserLocation } from '../hooks/useLocation';

const Loc = () => {

    const [Data, SetData] = useState(null)

    async function GetLoc() {
        let response = await getUserLocation()
        console.log("Location Hook response : ", response);

    }

    async function CallHello() {
        try {
            let resp = await fetch('/api/location', {
                method: 'GET',
                cache: 'no-store',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                }
            })

            let { data } = await resp.json()
            // IMPORTANT TO CONVERT TO JSON

            console.log("Recieved from API : ", data);
            SetData(data)


        } catch (e) {

            throw new Error("Error occured while calling Location API")
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        GetLoc()
        CallHello()
    }, [])
    return (
        <div>
            Data from Location API : {Data}
        </div>
    )
}

export default Loc
```

Now just **import** this **`<Loc />` component** in your page.js to see it run.

**Output:**

In browser :

1. Popup for location
2. In Console :

`Recieved from API :  Location API says Hello !! Location Hook response :  {latitude: someNumbers, longitude:someNumbers } Location Hook response :  {latitude:someNumbers , longitude:someNumbers }`

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use the whole URL instead of `/api/location`.

Maybe store the route link in an env and use `${API_URL}/api/location`